# ngModelChange does not trigger when re-inputting identical value

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying to implement a maximum value limit on a number input field, such that when a user tries to enter a value higher than the limit, the input field will be reset to the maximum value allowed. Afterwards an action is received by a reducer that updates the value in the store.

Example code below. Please excuse the poor code: I'm quite inexperienced with RXJS/NGRX. If anyone has a better solution I'm all ears.

component.ts

```js
export class InputAmountComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public item: FormGroup;
  @Input() public appState: AppState;

  @Output() public inputAmountEmitter: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  inputChanged$: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

  maxAmount = environment.defaultMaxAmountPayablePoundsOrDollars;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.inputChanged$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
    )
      .subscribe((newValue) => {
        if (this.maxAmount && newValue > this.maxAmount) {
          console.log('resetting')
          this.item.controls['amount'].setValue(this.maxAmount);
        }
        else {
          console.log('dispatching')
          this.store.dispatch(new AppActions.UpdateAmount(newValue));
        }
      });
  }

 updateValue(newValue: number) {    
    console.log('changed')
    if (this.getAmount().valid) {
      this.inputChanged$.next(newValue);
    }
  }

//...rest of the code
```

component.html

```html
...// more html
<div class="col-10">
      <input
        class="form-control"
        appCurrencyInputMask
        (ngModelChange)="updateValue($event)"
        formControlName="amount"
        title="amount"
        required
      />
  </div>
...// more html
```

While testing this solution I've encountered this odd behaviour:

1. user inputs 330000
2. app resets to 30000 (max value allowed)
3. user inputs 330000 again
4. nothing happens (but I would expect a reset as per step 2)

contrast with:

1. user inputs 330000
2. app resets to 30000 (max value allowed)
3. user inputs 320000
4. app resets to 30000

Could anyone explain why this is happening and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ngModel` and `ngModelChange` with reactive forms. It was considered a bad practice in older versions of Angular, and support of mixing it up was dropped (or was supposed to be dropped at least) in Angular 7.
If you're using this on on Angular >= 7, you should either get warnings or errors thrown.

Anyway - drop the `ngModelChange`, drop the whole `inputChanged$` since it's not needed.

```
// Subscribe directly to changes in the form
this.item.get('amount').valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
  )
  .subscribe(newValue => {
    if (this.maxAmount && newValue > this.maxAmount) {
      console.log('resetting');
      // Update the value without emitting event so you don't enter endless loop.
      this.item.get('amount').setValue(this.maxAmount, {
        emitEvent: false
      });
    }
    else {
      console.log('dispatching');
      this.store.dispatch(new AppActions.UpdateAmount(newValue));
    }
  });
```

Written from top of my head, so take that with a grain of salt.
Also, I think `required` should be handled by validator as well instead of being a part of the markup - you'll probably have the same issue with this since it won't work with reactive forms.

On a side note - in most of the use cases, updating the value this way is considered bad UX. Usually you'll be better off with adding a validator and display a validation error as long as the input value is not valid. This way you'll let user know WHAT is wrong and let him manually fix his error to the value of this choosing.